# How do i parse a query having a subquery using JSqlparser

Tags: java, mysql, jsqlparser

I am trying to parse a query which has a subquery like this :

```
SELECT column_name [, column_name ] FROM   table1 [, table2 ] WHERE  column_name OPERATOR
  (SELECT column_name [, column_name ]
  FROM table1 [, table2 ]
  [WHERE])
```

by using **JSqlParser** in java. Is it possible to parse it using JSqlParser ? If not please suggest a better approach.

Comment: it is possible... can you please more details like what are the things you wanted out of that.. that would be more helpful.